# Can web application in a container stop itself

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a case where a java application that is to be managed can be running within tcserver or Apache Tomcat or as a standalone java process. I know tcserver and tomcat expose mbeans/url endpoints to start/stop but they are different and I am trying to find a generic common way covering all 3 cases to stop an application. A stand alone process can exit itself easily but for a container managed application, what would be the best way?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'stop'. An application-stopped state can be different to a webapp-stopped state. For application-stopped, put a servlet filter in your app that reads a `stopped` flag. If `true`, then the filter returns "This application is stopped" to the user.

Comment: Stop means stopping the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

Same way as a standalone app - just `System.exit(0)`.

Or, if this is on Unix, `kill <pid>`

Comment: System.exit(0) will work as long as there's no SecurityManager installed